# How to parse json file content, containing characters like $, { in values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

I have multiple json file in a folder.

**What I have to achieve ?**

I have to write a function, to traverse through all files inside that folder, and return a JSON array with filename as key and content as value.

```
[ {jsonFileName1:content1}, {jsonFileName2:content2}, {jsonFileName3:content3} ]
```

**Special condition**

Each file content contains few special characters like $,{.

*For Example :*

```
{
        "_id": "${obj2.result.id}",
        "someKey" : ${obj1.result.someValue}
}
```

**What Problem I am facing**

While parsing file content, it is throws exception.

Note : I cant enclose `${obj1.result.someValue}` in quotes.

**Code :**

```
function readFileAsync(){
    const pathUrl = pathToDir;
    readFileNamesInDir(pathUrl)
    .then((fileNames)=>{
        console.log(fileNames);
        const pTempArr = [];
        fileNames.forEach(function(filename) {
           pTempArr.push( readAndGetFilesContent(pathUrl, filename) );
        });

        return Promise.all( pTempArr );
    })
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}

function readFileNamesInDir(dirPath){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        fs.readdir(dirPath, function(err, filenames) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(filenames)
        });
    });
}


function readAndGetFilesContent(pathToFile, fileName){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        fs.readFile(pathToFile + fileName,'utf8', function(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }

            const tmp = {};
            tmp[fileName] =  content;

            resolve( tmp );
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: If you have the file as it is then it isn't JSON (and not a JSON file) and you cannot use `JSON.parse`. You'd have to write your own parser or make the string valid JSON somehow.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for commenting. Can you help me little bit how can I write that function.